# Traceback issue: can't multiply sequence by non-int type 'float'? [Python 3.2.5.1]

Tags: python, traceback

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Portable Python 3.2.5.1/Tasks/Wk7", line 16, in**

```
monthlySalary = hourPay * 0.1
```

**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'**

```
#Input hoursWorked
#Input hourPay
#Ask “Consultancy income? (Leave blank if none)”
#   If value:
#       Input consultFee
#       monthlySalary = ((hourPay - (hourPay * 0.1)) * hoursWorked) + (consultFee – (consultFee * 0.2))
#   Elif no value:
#       monthlySalary = hoursWorked * hourPay
#print (“The monthly wage is $”,monthlySalary)

hoursWorked = input ("Hours worked: ")
hourPay = input ("Hour pay: $")

consultFee = input ("Consultant fee? (Leave blank if none): $")
consultFee == ''
monthlySalary = hourPay * 0.1
'' == False
monthlySalary = ((hourPay - (hourPay * 0.1)) * hoursWorked) + (consultFee - (consultFee * 0.2))

print ("The monthly salary is: $",(int(monthlySalary)))
```

Comment: It might be that input returns string, apply float or int functions on hourPay before multiplication.

Comment: int(input( whoops, forgot that

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
monthlySalary = hourPay * 0.1
```

to

```
monthlySalary = float(hourPay) * 0.1
```

The reason is that input or raw input are taking in strings that you must first convert to their proper type.

Comment: Please do not answer obvious duplicate questions, and if you feel the need to do so, at least provide an answer that explains the issue, not just proposes a fix that leaves OP no wiser than before.